# Efficient Way to Read from ifstream to stringstream

Tags: c++

I have this function:

```
void GetLine(std::stringstream &output,std::ifstream &input,char C){
    static std::string Line;
    std::getline(input,Line,C);
    output.str(Line);
}
```

How can I make it more efficient as to not copy the data more times that I have to.

Edit: Removed static to simplify code, fixed syntax error. No error checking is done because it doesn't need to be done inside this function.

Comment: Related: The use of a static line buffer in this function has a *horrible* code smell, in particular since there is **no** io check to know the `getline` even *worked*. I don't know what problem that is intended to solve, but I'm fairly confident that *isn't* the way to do it.

Comment: [Set the `streambuf` pointer?](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/rdbuf)

Comment: Why do you want to do it?

Comment: Is that a special usage for `std::getline`, i can't even compile it? Well assuming you want to use it the way i'v read about it, does getting a single line need to be in a function? you could just do something like `for(std::string Line; std::getline(input, Line, input.widen(C));) output << Line << C;` to read an entire file into output, each loop in the for loop is another line from the file.

Answer (score 2):

Yout main performance problem isn't copying, it's memory allocation. Assuming you actually removed the static, your stirng object is located in stack memory, but the string data in located in memory dynamicallty allocated on the heap. Since you are constructing your string operation each time, you have one or more dynamic allocations and a free for each line copied. These are very expensive allocations.

Making the string static will help with timing at the expense of memory. In most library implementations, getline will not change the amount of memory allocated to hold string data. So the string buffer will expand to the size of the largest string read from the file and stay there. But since the string object is static you have no way to release this memory. There are other ways to structure the program that can resolve this problem.

If this piece of code is really the hold-up in your code (how do you know it is?), and your input has a maximum line length, then don't use a std::string and use istream::getline to read into a character array. This will set a error in the ifstream if you encounter a line longer than your buffer. Inserting into a character array is faster tha inserting into a string. However, I'd be surprised if this code is really taking that much time.